# When passing value to control return view loads without CSS and JS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is the 6th project I have done using the ASP.NET MVC.

For this, I got an uncommon error.

I created CRUD operation views for a model. `Index` is showing as usual, and when hit to the `Create` It also comes as usual way, But when I click `Edit` button and pass the Item Id to the controller, the view returns with no `CSS` and `JS`.

Then I tried in the controller hardcoding the Id to the `where` condition and nothing passed from the view to the controller with the action, Then the `Edit` views comes with as expected.

I have never encountered this error before. I thought this might be the Theme I have used. So I have created another project and used another theme. But Still the same issue.

Anyone got this error and solution. ?

This is how I passed the id to the action

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { Id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary pull-right" })
```

This is the Action

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
        {
             
            var countries = db.Countries.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
            if (countries == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(countries);
        }
```

Then I tried this

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { @class = "btn btn-primary pull-right" })
```

Nothing passes from the view. Then the Edit view comes in a normal way

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
        {
             
            var countries = db.Countries.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == 51);
            if (countries == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(countries);
        }
```

[image]

In the console, I found this kind of errors, which saying `Loading failed for the source`

`GEThttps://localhost:7160/Country/Theme/vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js`

Here this is `https://localhost:7160/Country` the controller address and don't know why returning with the script location after the Controller address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add ~/ to your css and js sources

Comment: I can't Belive. It worked. I again opened up my previous projects and they contain "../.css" and they are working without any errors. But for this this worked. Thanks